# Deserializing polymorphic type in Jackson using readValue with passed derived class

Tags: generics, jackson, polymorphism

I have a method where I want to use Jackson to deserialize a value from the inherited class but not knowing which inherited class it is.

Using an example class structure and skeleton code to explain my issue:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
  private String make; 
}

public class Car extends Vehicle { }

public class ProcessStuff {

  // how to construct parameter so I know what class to use, Vehicle<?>?
  private processThis(String jsonDataString, Vehicle<?> vehicle) {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  
    // if knew class I could read like this
    // Car car = objectMapper.readValue(jsonDataString, new TypeReference<Car>() {}); 

    // how to readValue from unknown derived class? 
    // second parameter does not compile
    final Vehicle aVehicleInstance = objectMapper.readValue(jsonDataString, new vehicle);
  }
}
```

Calling processThis

```
  // or should I pass Car.class or what?
  processThis(jsonDataString, New Car());
```

Comment: Somewhere in the json it should be a property indicating the type or classname or similar of the class you would to serialize and combining it with `JsonTypeInfo` would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution:

```
public class ProcessStuff() {

  private processThis(String jsonDataString, Class myVehicleClass) {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final Vehicle aVehicleInstance = objectMapper.readValue(jsonDataString, new vehicle);
    Vehicle <?> aVehicleInstance = null;
    try {
        aVehicleInstance = (Vehicle <?>) objectMapper.readValue(jsonDataString, myVehicleClass);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
       // log error
    }
  } 
}
```

Called by

```
processThis(jsonDataString, Car.class);
```